# Change menu name openerp

Tags: python, xml, odoo, overwrite

I want to change an `openerp` module menu name.

I know how to do it, i'ts actually pretty easy, but this one is a core module `sale` and i don't want to touch it's code, because of updates issues and stuff.

So, i'll need to inherit this `view` and change it's name, from another module, can i do this without a `module.py` or a full `__init__.py` file?

Just the `openerp` manifest file and an `xml` to overwrite it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can. you just need to create a module with two files. one is `__openerp__.py` with correct dependency to the base modules and an xml file for updating the menu name.

Comment: I wanted to manage the same as NeoVe, change a menu name through a custom module. I achieved it, but: The new menu name I've chosen is not being recognized by the traslation files when I export a translation, so I can't translate it. Moreover, I have to synchronize terms each time I update the openerp service, because the new name is overwritten by the old. How can I, at least, include the new menu name in the translation file?

Comment: how do you created po file?in the settings/translations you can see menu to export translations. export the pot file and then edit the file and add translations and save as po file.